# Как получить посты в группе Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Как получить записи группы?
Делаю такой запрос https://graph.facebook.com/idgroup/feed?&access_token=
Выдает ошибку Requires either admin with granted managed_group pemissions or member\n      using installed app.
Какой способ получения записей групп имеется?